# Как загрузить фотографию в базу данных mySQL с html формы при помощи php и получить её обратно?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных

сделал небольшую новостную ленту на php, с пользователем имеющим возможность добавлять записи в базу данных и удалять их. Имеется таблица news со следующими полями: id, title, text, date. Можно ли создать поле для фотографии, чтобы для конкретной новости можно было загрузить свое фото, а потом его получить вместе с остальными полями и вывести в ленту? И как это сделать?

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="add_post" class="d-flex justify-content-between" method="POST" action="post.php">
                    <div class="add-post__left">
                        <h3>Add new post</h3>
                        <div class="add-post__form-set">
                            <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" required>
                            <textarea name="text" placeholder="Text" required></textarea>
                            <div style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
                                <span>Прикпепить фото: </span>
                                <input type="file" name="img" id="upload_photo">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="add-post__right">
                        <button type="submit" name="post">Post</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: ответ на ваш вопрос http://www.internet-technologies.ru/articles/zagruzka-izobrazheniy-v-bazu-dannyh-ili-na-server-s-pomoschyu-html-php-i-mysql.html

Comment: @GENESIS $imagename = $_FILES["img"]["name"];
$imagetmp = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'])); 
$sql = "INSERT INTO news (`title`, `text`, `date`, `img`) VALUES ('$title', '$text', now(), '$imagetmp')";
Вот так я добавлял, но при выводе выводит не фото, а километры символов..В чем может быть проблема??

Comment: Чтобы сохранить изображение в базе, нужно использовать для столбца в таблице тип данных blob. MySQL использует BLOB для хранения двоичных данных. Вы можете использовать BLOB TINYBLOB, BLOB, MEDIUMBLOB или LONGBLOB в зависимости от размера загружаемого рисунка.

Comment: вы сохранили только $imagetmp  а нужно еще $imagename

Comment: А лучше в БД сохранять путь до изображения на диске, чем его данные.